# Access networkshare from 2 different domains

Tags: network-shares, group-policy, windows-domain, windows-server-2016

I have the following situation:

- A stand-alone server which has a folder shared (win 2k8 r2).
- A domain controller with terminal server (2x win 2016).
- Another domain controller with terminal server (2x win 2016).

The situation is that these are 2 companies who used to be together, who are splitting up. Both need access to the same database which is hosted on the stand-alone server, and in no way, can I split this data or copy it and bring them over to the domain controllers.

I need to somehow make it so that when you log into the terminal server, a drive letter pops up that shows the share to this server without identifying the server itself.

I have setup the share to allow for guest access, so if I fire up the share in explorer, it comes with a login prompt, but regardless of what I enter, I get in.

If I use group policy to map network drives, it refuses to connect. Given that I can't use the option to enter credentials (deprecated feature), how can I manage to do this?

I've considered using a logon script, but that would reveal the server. I preferably would not want to use that.

Is it perhaps possible to access the share from the DC itself, then share the share as a new share and use that new share in my group policy? If so, how do I set that up?

Any other method you know that could work here?

Comment: Why not use local accounts ?

Comment: @Overmind that's the first thing I thought of, but both domains have too many users, so setting up a user each time a new user is made just isn't going to work. I tried with a default user, but from the GPO, I can't setup with another username. Your answer may work though. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using a logon script to map the network drive, then use group policy to remove and remap it.

When the connection was there once, group policy had no trouble connecting to it another time.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a forest trust with the two domains (and use VPN connection if necessary - if the split was external).

Open Active Directory Domains and Trusts

- In the console tree, right-click the domain node for the forest root domain, and then click Properties.
- Trust tab --> New Trust --> Next.
- On the Trust Name page, type the DNS name (or NetBIOS name) of another forest, and then click Next.
- Trust Type page --> Forest trust --> Next.
- On the Direction of Trust page, do one of the following:

To create a two-way, forest trust, use Two-way.

Users in this forest and users in the specified forest can access resources in either forest. To create a one-way, incoming forest trust, select One-way:incoming. Users in the specified forest will not be able to access any resources in this forest. To create a one-way, outgoing forest trust, use One-way:outgoing.

Users in this forest will not be able to access any resources in the specified forest. Continue to and the wizard.

Additional information can be found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc740018(v=ws.10)) and [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2003/cc773178(v=ws.10)).

Comment: Will this also work if the stand-alone server is not in a domain? I mean, I could in theory make it its own domain, but if it can be without, that would be better I think.

Comment: The target server should be in one of the domains. If you want it not to be, just use a local account of the server to access it from both domains, bu that is less comfortable for the users.

Comment: I wasn't able to get this to work, but my approach seemed to work in the end, which basically is using a logon script to connect to the drive first, then group policy to reconnect to it a second time. The problem with your question is that I could not make the lone server part of either domain for security reasons, and I then ran into DNS issues not being able to create a trust between the two. Thanks for the help though. +1 for the effort.